# How to automate an upload process with talend whenever a file is moved into a specific folder

Tags: salesforce, etl, talend

I have **zero** experience with ETL.
Whenever a file(a .csv) is moved into a specific folder, it should be uploaded to SalesForce I don't know how to get this automated flow.
I hope I was clear enough.
I gotta use the opensource version, any helpful links or resources will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely use Talend Open Studio for ESB : this studio contains 'Routes' functionalities : you'll be able to use a cFile component, which will check your folder for new files, and raise an event that will propagate throughout the route to a designed endpoint (for example a salesForce API). Talend ESB maps Apache Camel components , which are well documented.
Check about Routes with Talend for ESB, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

We have tFileExists component, you can use that and configure to check the file.
Also you have tFileWait component, where you can define the frame of the arrival of the files and the number of iterations it has to check the file.

But I would suggest if you have any scheduling tool, use file watcher concept and then use talend job to upload the file to a specific location.

Using talend itself to check the file arrival is not a feasible way as the jobs has be in running state continuously which consumes more java resource

Comment: Thank you so much,
Could you suggest me any good scheduling tools for this task?

Comment: Contol M is one of the best scheduling. Besides you have many tools like Obsidian, Cron Jobs in Unix, if your environment is windows, you can use windows schedulers as well.